# Alasql - How to get the sheet names from an xlsx file?

Tags: xlsx, alasql

According to: https://github.com/agershun/alasql/wiki/XLSX you can send in the sheetid to read out a different sheet.

I can't however find any way to read out the available sheets.

Does anyone know how this should be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using alasql, first read your workbook yourself using the xlsx plugin

```
// file is instanceof File object
let workbook = XLSX.read(URL.createObjectURL(file));
console.log(workbook.SheetNames);
```

Comment: hi,how to get sheet by it's name..?

Comment: I'm no longer using alasql for it but without alasql: workbook.Sheets['sheetname'], using alasql just as in the link of my question: alasql.promise('select * from xlsx("cities.xlsx",{sheetid:"sheetname"})')